# Dotted name in AppConfig

Tags: django, django-apps

With django 1.7 they added support for configuration classes instead of the magic string from previous versions.

My project has several applications into a folder named `apps` which is added to the `PYTHON_PATH`.

After adding a simple `AppConfig` derived class I'm running into many import errors and I want to rule out silly mistakes.

Suppose this structure:

```
project_root/
    my_project/
    apps/
        my_app/
        another_app/
```

Would it be correct to have this config?:

```
# my_app/apps.py
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.my_app'


# my_app/__init__.py
default_app_config='apps.my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'

# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'apps.myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
    ...
)
```

Curently the project fails when trying to import `models` (or `tasks` or any other module) issuing:

```
from apps.my_app.tasks import AwesomeTask

ImportError: no module named my_app.tasks
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? That code snippet could be correct.

Comment: Updated the question to include the error.

Comment: What if you just include `my_app.tasks`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20866424/248065 might be related.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to your problem. I have the same issue. All my apps are in a subfolder and the ones I configure AppConfig for cannot be found...

Comment: No solution, just defined the app_config without `apps.` worked the same... Need to go back and create a minimal example to answer this question...

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by renaming the **apps** folder. It was somehow conflicting with Django internals system.

I hope this helps someone.